# laravel 10, laravel webscockets secure (wss) unable to connect while redirect form ngnix

Tags: php, laravel-10, laravel-echo, laravel-websockets

Working on Laravel 10, with Laravel WebSockets, pusher, and laravel-echo. Using Ngnix I added a self-signed SSL certificate, the application is working in https but the web socket secure is not connecting to the local machine (windows).

```
listen 80 ;     
server_name real.web.com; 

listen 443 ssl;
ssl on;
ssl_certificate C:\certificate\websock\real.web.pem;
ssl_certificate_key C:\certificate\websock\private-key.pem;

root E:\\real-web\\public;

location / 
{
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}           

location ~ \.php$ 
{
    try_files $uri /index.php = 404;
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:8001;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location  /ws 
{
    proxy_pass             http://127.0.0.1:6001;
    proxy_set_header Host  $host;
    proxy_read_timeout     60;
    proxy_connect_timeout  60;
    proxy_redirect         off;

    # Allow the use of websockets
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

.env

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=Zigma.v.0.01
PUSHER_APP_KEY=Zigma@123
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=Zigma@!@#
PUSHER_HOST=127.0.0.1
PUSHER_PORT=6001
PUSHER_SCHEME=http
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
```

bootstrap.js

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER ?? 'mt1',
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 80, 
    wssPort:  443, 
    forceTLS: (import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME ?? 'https') === 'https',
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'], 
});
```